# How do I get php documentation on the console?

Tags: php

In perl I can use `perldoc -i XML::Parser` to get the manual on the command line. Is there a similar tool for php?

I can do: `php --rf str_repeat`, but it doesn't give me much info.

I was able to download html manual here: https://www.php.net/get/php_manual_en.tar.gz/from/a/mirror. Is it possible to access and search it from the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the sidebar at http://php.net/download-docs.php

> The manual is also available via *nix style man pages. To install and use:
>
> Install: `pear install doc.php.net/pman`
>   Upgrade: `pear upgrade doc.php.net/pman`
>   Example usage: `pman strlen`